# What is the best way to connect a cognito user with a real database user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a react native app build with AWS Amplify. In this I have a custom authentication flow creating a cognito user and a post confirmation lambda trigger creating a real dynamoDB user. But the problem arise when I want to query this real user in my app home screen. At present I do it as follows, I first get the current authenticated user from cognito and then from the data receive I query real database user, but sometimes at first this fail to get the user but when I refresh the screen I get the user back. I want to know the best way to do this ?

My code,

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { DataStore} from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { User } from "../src/models";

const [user , setUser] = useState <User[]>([]);
const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

const getUser = async () => {

try{
    const userData = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const currentUserPhone = userData.attributes.phone_number
    
    if(currentUserPhone){  
     await DataStore.query(User, d => d.Phonenumb("eq", currentUserPhone)).then(setUser);
     console.log("getting user in home");
     setReady(true);
    } else{
     setReady(false);
    }
  } catch(e){
    setReady(false);
    console.log(e)
  }

}

useEffect(() => {
    
  getUser();
     
}, []);

return(

<View>
 {ready === true &&(<Text>Hello {user?.name}</Text>)}
 {ready === false &&(<Text>No user</Text>)}
</View>

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure data is synced before querying. Call `start` and listen for `ready` event.

```
await DataStore.start();
```

```
Hub.listen('datastore', (data) => {
  const  { event } = data.payload;
  if (event === "ready") {
    // TODO
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes to manually start the sync process we have to run 'await DataStore.start()', But in the documentation they have stated that 'Synchronization starts automatically whenever you run any of the following methods such as 'DataStore.query()'. Can you explain your answer ? thanks.

Comment: Sorry actually this answer is correct, when the app is started with no local data it doesn't start to sync until the execution of the first query. So what I did was as this answer explain I added the listener in my navigation so to only render my home screen only if the datastore is ready. Now everything works flawlessly.